# Avoiding warnings of undefined functions while compiling

Tags: byte-compilation, warning

I have a lot of code in my init file like this:

```
(when library-is-available
  ;; Code that use that uses functions from library
)
```

However, I get warnings that the functions that I am using are not known to be defined.
What is an easy way to avoid these warnings?
Can I perhaps ignore these code parts and not include them in the compiled file?

Comment: what about something like this?:

 `(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cl-lib))

(defun foo ()
  (cl-incf (point)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node [Warning Tips](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Warning-Tips.html) of the Elisp manual tells us:

> • To avoid a compiler warning about an undefined function
> that you know *will* be defined, use a `declare-function` statement
> (see [Declaring Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Declaring-Functions.html)).
>
> • If you use many functions, macros, and variables from a certain
> file, you can add a `require` (see [require: Named Features](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html)) for
> that package to avoid compilation warnings for them, like this:
>
> ```
>      (require 'foo)
> ```
>
> If you need only *macros* from some file, you can require it only at
> compile time (see [Eval During Compile](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval-During-Compile.html)).  For instance,
>
> ```
>      (eval-when-compile
>        (require 'foo))
> ```